# How to know which certificate(s) QNetworkAccessManager uses during an SSL/TLS handshake?

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, embedded-linux

I am using the class `QNetworkAccessManager` to establish an HTTPS connexion with a remote server. The connexion works well but i will need to update the certificates eventually.

I don't know much about SSL and i would like to clarify one point.

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#encrypted, the initial SSL handshake seems to works fine because the following slot connected to the `QNetworkAccessManager` signal `encrypted(QNetworkReply*)` is called :

```
void MyAccessManager::onEncrypted(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    Q_UNUSED(rep)
    qDebug() << "SSL/TLS handshake success";
}
```

This is an embedded Linux on which several `.crt` files are already installed in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` and a list of `.pem` files in `/etc/ssl/certs/`

My understanding is that Qt is able to locate those files automatically because when i get the `QSslConfiguration` from the `QNetworkRequest` i can see the list of `QSslCertificate` in use, for example with :

```
QSslConfiguration conf = myNetworkRequest.sslConfiguration();

for (int i = 0; i < conf.caCertificates().size(); i++)
    qDebug() << conf.caCertificates().at(i).subjectInfo(QSslCertificate::Organization);
```

and the output i have is :

```
QDEBUG : ("DigiCert Inc")
QDEBUG : ("VeriSign, Inc.")
QDEBUG : ("GlobalSign")
...
```

My question is how is it possible to see which of these certificates and files, were effectively used by `QSslSocket` for this specific connexion ?

Thank you.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like the `encrypted` signal hands you a `QNetworkReply`, which contains a [`sslConfiguration`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#sslConfiguration). I'd guess this [`QSslConfiguration`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslconfiguration.html) should contain some information about certificates.

Comment: `QNetworkReply` gives me the same list as above

Comment: did you use [`peerCertificate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslconfiguration.html#peerCertificate)?

Comment: No i have used `caCertificates()`. So as you suggested, i have used `peerCertificate()` and also  `peerCertificateChain()` from the `QNetworkReply` and indeed i can see the list of `QSslCertificate` of the peer. From there, how can i retrieve the corresponding `.crt` or `.pem` files ?

Comment: in the [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslcertificate.cpp.html#_ZN15QSslCertificate8fromPathERK7QStringN4QSsl14EncodingFormatEN7QRegExp13PatternSyntaxE), it doesn't look like the path gets stored anywhere